# Optional param bool in Contains of CosmosDB is breaking query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

```
select * from c 
where c.__type = @type 
and CONTAINS(c.title, @search, @ignoretest)
and (NOT IS_DEFINED(c.archived) or c.archived = false) 
and (NOT IS_DEFINED(c.deleted) or c.deleted = null)
```

```
var sqlParams = new SqlParameterCollection();
sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter { Name = "@ignoretest", Value = true });
```

If I have boolean `@ignoreTest` param then my query is not working. What are the reasons? documentation is saying I can use this optional param https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-contains

Comment: Please edit your question to show what your inputs are, including what you're searching for. That third parameter is for performing a case-insensitive search. We can't tell what you mean by "my query is not working" without further details.

Comment: `@type = Product;
@search = "test"`
my item has "Test" title instead "test" so query is not loading "Test" product